# changing position of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following select box. I tried playing around with width and height, and selecting lis or uls from select#id, but nothing worked. How can I change the position of where the dropdown appears, as it is currently obstructing the current selected value?

```
 <select id="something" type="text"
                                class="characteristic-text" data-ng-model="vehicle.info.used"
                                data-ng-options="option for option in used.options"
                                ></select>
```

Comment: Your options are limited https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/ I would suggest looking into a JavaScript plugin that connects to a hidden drop down

Answer (score -1, accepted):

do you have a css file? or do you do the styling in the HTML part?

you can use padding for positioning, left, right, etc.
Basically in css file since your ID is something so, 
as an example:

`#something{
     padding-left:60px;
}`